# How to preload pose Net in p5js?

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

So i created a breakout game using p5js, poseNet and Ml5 js and the game runs before loading model, how do i wait for all the model to load before starting the setup and draw function in p5js,

I tried Preload function in p5js
Please help

Comment: What happened when you tried the preload function?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to prevent the draw function from looping until the poseNet method has called the callback function. In the example below this would be modelLoaded(). This function is fired when the Model is loaded.

Example code:

```
function setup(){
    // Don't loop yet
    noLoop(); 

    // Example uses a video element
    const video = document.getElementById("video");

    // Create a new poseNet method
    const poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelLoaded);
}

// Callback function for when the model is loaded
function modelLoaded() {
    console.log("Model Loaded!");

    // Start the draw() loop
    loop();
}

function draw(){
    // Your code here
}
```